# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't align properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a bootstrap nav (v2.3.2) and the formatting looks like:

**This:**
[wrong http://tastytreatthursday.com/nav1.jpg](http://tastytreatthursday.com/nav1.jpg)

**Instead of this:**
[wrong http://tastytreatthursday.com/nav2.jpg](http://tastytreatthursday.com/nav2.jpg)

```
<div class="navbar visible-desktop visible-tablet">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="http://myurl" style="margin:0; padding:0;"><img style="z-index:1; position:relative;" height="125px" width="125px" src="myLogo.png"></a>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<!--item-->
  <li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
  Test title<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2 Test 2 Test 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<!--item-->
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you made any changes to the CSS, or is it just default bootstrap CSS?

Comment: It is all default.  I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would make it easier to answer your question with a Fiddle of what you have. Looks like you may have done changes to your CSS, as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5vS/, it seems to work properly with your same html.

Even if you add:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Shows properly, so you must have changed something.

Comment: I did note from the link of your mage, that you are running that on WordPress, so it might be some conflict of CSS from WP with Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes it is inside of WP, I think you might be on to something here.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site you are making that? Should be easy to verify if it's some WP CSS that is generating that conflict.

Comment: I see there is a styles.css in there, where you are applying: `.navbar .nav li { width: 100px; /* or whatever width you want for items */`. That is making the width of the list item 100px. There are also some other modifications in there to the default CSS.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  I totally overlooked it somehow.  Looks like I can take it from here!

Comment: Good luck! Hope you can get it working properly. If anything, just shoot another comment and I, or someone else, might be able to help further :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me. Makere usre you put it inside a row class and inside another span class. When I put the code it work like a charm.

```
<section class="row-fluid ">
    <aside class="span12">
      <div class="navbar visible-desktop visible-tablet">
        <div class="navbar-inner"> <a class="brand" href="http://myurl" style="margin:0; padding:0;"><img style="z-index:1; position:relative;" height="125px" width="125px" src="wp-content/themes/img/lcva_logo.png"></a>
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <!--item-->
            <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Test title<span class="caret"></span> </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test 2 Test 2 Test 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <!--item-->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </section>
```